# Beginner in Java - String format = " | %-"+maxW[j]+"s"; - What does this string do?

Tags: java, string, format

I am a noob in Java and I came across the code below and couldn't figure out its function.
 maxw[] is an array of type int.
 row[] is an array of type String.

```
             String format = " | %-"+maxW[i]+"s";
       System.out.printf(format,row[i]);
```

My questions is :
 For this statement : System.out.printf(format,row[i]); only '|' and after that value of row[i] are getting printed so why are '%- (value of maxW[i]) and 's' not getting printed ?

Answer (score 5):

Java format specifiers are described [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

This code is dynamically creating a format specifier that will left-justify a string (row[i]) with a minimum width specified by maxW[i].

Format specifiers follow the pattern on the first line below. Underneath I've aligned the code above, showing where it fits into the pattern.

```
    %[argument_index$][flags] [width] [.precision]conversion
" | %                  -     "+maxW[i]           +"s";
```

Answer (score 0):

The format method assumes the String decribes a format as it states in the documentation.  It handles %x or the like a special way replacing it with the first, second etc argument.

If you want to know more I suggest you read the Javadoc for this method.